# Gostaria de saber como faço para mudar a cor dos itens selecionados, ActionBar?

Tags: android, actionbar, android-styles

[image: Gostaria de saber como faço para mudar a cor dos itens selecionados]

```
<!-- styles.xml -->    

<resources>

    <!--  Base do  tema da aplicação. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>

     <!-- Cor do Menu -->
    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<!-- color.xml -->    


<resources>

    <!--cor principal do aplicativo-->
    <color name="colorPrimary">#93662f</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#3a1a0b</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#93662f</color>

    <!--deslize para baixo atualizar a cor da animação-->
    <color name="orange">#FF9900</color>
    <color name="green">#009900</color>
    <color name="blue">#000099</color>
    <color name="red">#ff0015</color>

    <!--outra cor-->
    <color name="background_color">#e2e2e2</color>
    <color name="divider">#f2f2f2</color>
    <color name="text_color">#525252</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode mudar a cor de um View ao ser pressionado(exemplo: textView, button etc) criando Selectores:

**drawable/selector.xml:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/custom_color"/>
    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

**color/custom_color.xml:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
    <item android:color="@color/blue_bt_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/blue_bt"/>
</selector>
```

E na sua View adicione:

```
android:background ="@drawable/selector
```

Não sei como você pode implementar isto no ActionBar mas espero que isto possa o ajudar.